# Querydsl: a field is not properly initialised on the child class

Tags: java, querydsl

Good day,

We are using qdsl to access our inherited objects. We have a parent class (`Parent`) which has a complicated object (`BasicProduct`) as a field. Then we have several children (one of them is `Child`). In the query we are trying to access the `BasicProduct` from the `QChild` autogenerated code. From what we have seen - the field to access the `BasicProduct` exists on both the `QParent` and `QChild` but only the one on the `QParent` is correctly initialised.

The structure of the objects is:

Parent object -

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
name="TYPE",
discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Parent

    //bunch of fields

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BASIC_PRODUCT_ID")
    protected BasicProduct basicProduct;
}
```

Child object -

```
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "Child")
public class Child extends Parent {
    //bunch of fields
}
```

The access query:

```
HibernateQuery query = new HibernateQuery(session);

query = query.distinct().from(thing)
.leftJoin(thing.childSet, child)
.leftJoin(child.basicProduct(), basicProduct)
.leftJoin(child.basicProduct().fieldA, fieldA)
.leftJoin(basicProduct.fieldB, fieldB);
```

The access query above fails to build. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have mixed types of entity accessor generation. Parent seems to have entityAccessors and Child does not. This could lead to issues when the fields in QChild do not get initialized.

Try to set entityAccessors on QChild too.

Comment: Thank you. That has saved us days of investigation. You are a god amongst men.

Comment: A god amongst men indeed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your generated `QChild`, it should contain the fields inherited from its parent (with a `///inherited` comment above the field). All inherited fields are `public final`, so you can use them.

That said, `basicProduct` is in `QChild`, and you can access it - remove brackets from your code

instead of

```
.leftJoin(child.basicProduct(), basicProduct)
```

you should have

```
.leftJoin(child.basicProduct, basicProduct)
```

Comment: The inherited field is auto-generated as protected. On the parent class it is public final.